# Android P Altbeacon BLE disable Foreground service does not cancel notification icon

Tags: android, altbeacon

Using Altbeacon 2.15, having BLE running as foreground service, I can enable and disable the service without any problem except on disabling the service, i still see foreground notification icon still appear on at least Android P ( i dont recall seeing the same on Android O, but i can't say for sure). Same code worked perfectly on Android 7.1.1.

this is the code i use on disabling BLE service

```
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
beaconManager.disableForegroundServiceScanning();
Log.d(logTag, "Cancelling foreground notification");
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(beaconManager.getForegroundServiceNotificationId());
```

Please let me know what is the right way to do!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `beaconManager.unbind(consumer)` or `regionBootstrap.disable()` depending on how you started scanning. This will actually shut down the scanning service.

Comment: I am actually calling beaconManager.unbind(this) already, but seems like BLE is still detecting.

Comment: here is my onDestroy
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
        if (beaconScanner.getMode() == ScanningMode.RANGING || beaconScanner.getMode() == ScanningMode.RANGING_MONITORING){
            stopBeaconRanging();
        }
        beaconManager.disableForegroundServiceScanning();
    }

but this code is not able to stop BLE scanning on Android P

Comment: do you have other suggestion, i can't really stop scanning until i uninstall the app now on Android P

Comment: I don't see why the service does not stop.  But even if it keeps running and it won't stop scanning by stopping rNlanging and monitoring, you could always set the scan period to 0 and the between scann period to  an infinite value.  If this really keeps scanning then somerhing is really wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

Make sure you cancel the notification correctly for Android O (API 26).

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
}
```